# Handling value in the parent when I dismiss a rootViewController in the child [SwiftUI]

Tags: swift, swiftui, dismiss, completionhandler

**ONLY SWIFTUI**

I'm using an `UIHostingController` and I want to handle when I dismiss a `rootViewController` from the parent

`MAINVIEW` ** [Parent]

```
let alertHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: SettingsView())
                                alertHostingController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
                                UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.present(alertHostingController, animated: false)
```

`SETTINGS VIEW` ** [Child]

```
 UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want to know when child dismissed in the parent...

Any ideas?

**Ps. I want to use the completion parameter but I don't know how to read it**

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol ChildDelegate: class {
    func childWasDismissed()
}

class ChildController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: ChildDelegate?

    deinit {
        delegate?.childWasDismissed()
    }
}
```

Something like that. Or the same with closure.

Comment: No. You should add this in your child and conform the parent to ChildDelegate.